# how to get image path from server drive

Tags: asp.net, image

How to get imgepath from server drive. I have all imges in C drive Chekout folder which included my projct. I want to display that image in my asp.net application. I did server path C:\Chekout but it is searchin in users local system not in server. Please Help me..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like this:

```
YourPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(YourFileName))
```

Comment: VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(YourFile) can i give "C:\Checkout\image.jpg" in place of YourFile